# failed to receive data from url via file_get_contents()

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3, curl

I get

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

when trying to access an url with `file_get_contents()`. however when calling it in a unix console with `curl -i` I get `200 ok`.

Calling only headers with `curl -I` gets `403 Forbidden`

How I can get content of this page via php? Why do I get different result with curl?

```
http://ajillion-customer-files.s3.amazonaws.com/reports/ff82f47836954b88adf57e42b85a82b5\?Signature\=FQNSVR%2Bs1XVu4UzP0%2BfscVmXsRc%3D\&Expires\=1434015848\&AWSAccessKeyId\=AKIAJ35DX3F5NPKSAKMQ
```

Comment: Format your question, please

Comment: Maybe the source file you're trying to get is blocking?

Comment: But when I try ' curl http://ajillion-customer-files.s3.amazonaws.com/reports/ff82f47836954b88adf57e42b85a82b5\?Signature\=FQNSVR%2Bs1XVu4UzP0%2BfscVmXsRc%3D\&Expires\=1434015848\&AWSAccessKeyId\=AKIAJ35DX3F5NPKSAKMQ
{"rows": [{"advertiser": "BM Fogzy", "hits": 0, "campaign": "BM Fozgy US (87417)", "revenue": 4.049, "source": 4, "impressions": 16196}]}' it's ok

Comment: Hey there. I formatted your question for you. Not sure what you mean with your comment, maybe add it to your question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your URL is backslash escaped for using a shell argument? Because of that the query parameters aren't properly read by the server.
If I run this:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('http://ajillion-customer-files.s3.amazonaws.com/reports/ff82f47836954b88adf57e42b85a82b5?Signature=FQNSVR%2Bs1XVu4UzP0%2BfscVmXsRc%3D&Expires=1434015848&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ35DX3F5NPKSAKMQ');
```

It works fine and returns:

```
{"rows": [{"advertiser": "BM Fogzy", "hits": 0, "campaign": "BM Fozgy US (87417)", "revenue": 4.049, "source": 4, "impressions": 16196}]}
```

Comment: Could you write more? I still get a negative result

Comment: could you include your the code you're running in the question?

Comment: I try to run this code `php -f "echo file_get_contents('http://ajillion-customer-files.s3.amazonaws.com/reports/ff82f47836954b88adf57e42b85a82b5?Signature=FQNSVR%2Bs1XVu4UzP0%2BfscVmXsRc%3D&Expires=1434015848&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ35DX3F5NPKSAKMQ');"`
`Could not open input file: echo file_get_contents('http://ajillion-customer-files.s3.amazonaws.com/reports/ff82f47836954b88adf57e42b85a82b5?Signature=FQNSVR%2Bs1XVu4UzP0%2BfscVmXsRc%3D&Expires=1434015848&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ35DX3F5NPKSAKMQ');`

Comment: I get 403 when you put that URL in the browser too right now. It looks like those S3 url expire or something like that.